# Python http_client error

Tags: python, django

I get below error when I run my code

```
ImportError: No module named http_client
```

Environment details

```
$ python --version 
2.7.6

django.VERSION
1.6.1
```

I think it is related to Python 3, but my default Python version is 2 still I am getting this. How to rectify it ?

Comment: Do you mean importing `httpclient`?

Comment: yes it is httpclient.

Comment: Then, why is the code trying to import `http_client` instead of `httpclient`?

Comment: Im using Django Rest Framework, Trace Report                                       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.utils.six.moves.http_client import responses

Comment: I narrowed little bit when I do "import rest_framework.decorators" I get this error "ImportError: No module named http_client"

Comment: Fixed it, the issue with DjangoRestFramework version I downgraded to lower version and it works well.